# Alternative to a CALL as a composition?

Tags: computation-models, functional-programming, interpreters

I've seen a numerous interesting abstract machines (i.e. CESK) and evaluators (diverse meta-circular S-expression evaluators, i.e. vau, COLA) and other models (concatenative, SK/Lambda calculus) which implement some novel(?) computational ideas, but almost every time each model boils down to:

Executing a stream of ***primitives*** (from a ***fixed set***) and giving means to combine/compose them.

And the only method of composing/reusing that I've ever seen is a function CALL (aka basic form of application, i.e. without talking about environments and other complex stuff).

Are there any alternative methods/theories? Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything on scholar google.

Comment: I think it depends on what it is meant by "composition". Ocaml functors might be called a form of composition. Haskell's typeclass instances like `instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (a, b)` compose two instances in one. CLOS in Lisp for oop-like compositionaity. Higher-kinded parameters of types in Scala/Haskell. There are many forms of high level compositional features in modern FP languages. I'm not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: @chi What I've meant was a slightly different thing: if you take a look at any meta-circular S expression evaluator and how 'apply' function works it ALWAYS boils down to a recursive case: either continue eval/apply further down or CALL some primitive, to end recursion. I am talking about this case. Why it ends in this case and are there any alternatives to that. Is any computational model, in the end, relies on composing primitives?
In the case of most FP languages, everything is based on 1 single mechanism - function application.

Comment: goto should work :o)

Comment: @AlbertHendriks only if it's conditional :D

Comment: what about languages like prolog?